# Wicket - Losing Session with target _blank

Tags: java, wicket

I have a quick question.
In my wicket application, I have to open an info-sheet from a table with a target="_blank" link.
The table is the result of a complex FORM so I want to keep the result table and allow the user to open the detailed result in a new page.
Unfortunally Wicket seems to lose session from the start page if the target page of link is the same application. When I return to the original page trying to do anythings, the page return to login screen.

Is there a way to keep session in every page I open?

Thanks

Comment: Are both pages from the same application? Which Wicket version are you using? Did you change any application configuration related to error pages?

Comment: Posting a bit of code would help us help you.  Have a look at http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the session was not bound yet. If you have a page, but it is not stateful (Wicket strives for pages to be stateless for as long as possible) the HttpSession will not be bound, and you will get a new session with each request.

In your form.onSubmit handler you might want to call:

```
getSession().bind();
```

This will fix the session for you.

Comment: I have the same issue when using wicket version > 1.5.2. If i change my project to use wicket 1.5.2, all ok with the session. I'll try your solution and test it with wicket 1.5.6. Thnx!